# Save attachments from multiple subfolders

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to save attachments from multiple subfolders.

My code is not iterating through subfolders, it's only saving one attachment.

```vb
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
 
Private Count As Integer
 
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim path_location As String
     
    '        Get the items in the Inbox folder
    Set objApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNameSpace = objApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Items = objNameSpace.Folders("Archives_May_2016").Folders("Inbox").Folders("subfolder1").Items
    path_location = "C: \emails" & "\Attachments\"
     
    For Each Item In Items
        Items.Item(1).Attachments.Count
        '        Initialize count
        strFile = Items.Item(1).Attachments.Item(1).FileName
        strFile = path_location & strFile
        Items.Item(1).Attachments.Item(1).SaveAsFile strFile
        Count = Count + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm Confused? Why are you using `Application Startup` to save attachment?

Answer (score 0):

You are always accessing the same file since you are setting `Items` before the `for loop`, but inside it you are doing:

```
Items.Item(1).Attachments.Count
```

Try changing the for loop to:

```
For Each Item In Items
    atts = Item.Attachments.Count

    For i = 1 to atts
        strFile = Item.Attachments.Item(i).FileName
        strFile = path_location & strFile
        Item.Attachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile
    Next

 Next
```